# Windows - access RDP file with encrypted password via multiple windows machines

Tags: powershell, rdp, windows-10, windows-11

I have an azure virtual machine which needs to be shared among the users to access a desktop software app.
Our PW wants this RDP to be accessible without user explicitly entering credentials.
I modified its RDP file to insert username & password as below.

```
username:s:{myexternaluser}
password 51:b: {my encrypted password}
```

I encrypted password using "powershell ConvertTo-SecureString" command on my machine.

This solution works on the machine on which password was encrypted but when I share this RDP file with other users, it won't work since their machine cannot decrypt the password and it asks them to enter password explicitly.

Is there any solution to make this work without requiring other machine to enter password?

Comment: Yes, there is a solution to this, but you will have to create the password value that's encrypted per machine and per user account on each machine. That's the way that works so try to figure out a way to get the value input into the RDP file on the user's desktop, etc. It will be per machine and per user on each machine too. Might have to use task scheduler and a dynamic powershell using `interactive login` or something fancy like that editing the per user RDP per login, connection, etc. to its triggers